# What is the problem in my query a d how to use sum() over(partition).. in my sql

Tags: mysql

PROBLEM :The total score of a hacker is the sum of their maximum scores for all of the challenges. Write a query to print the hacker_id, name, and total score of the hackers ordered by the descending score. If more than one hacker achieved the same total score, then sort the result by ascending hacker_id. Exclude all hackers with a total score of  from your result.

Tables

Hackers: The hacker_id is the id of the hacker, and name is the name of the hacker.

Submissions: The submission_id is the id of the submission, hacker_id is the id of the hacker who made the submission, challenge_id is the id of the challenge for which the submission belongs to, and score is the score of the submission.

My Sol:

```
select 
   h.hacker_id,
   h.name, 
   sum(s.score) over (partition by hacker_id) 
from hackers h 
inner join submissions as s on h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id
having sum(s.score)!=0
order by s.score desc, h.hacker_id;
```

Error : ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by hacker_id) from hackers h inner join submissions as s on h.hacker_' at line 1

Comment: What is your MySQL version? (I am not sure if MySQL5.7 already has this feature...)

Comment: Luuk is correct, you can use window functions in MySQL 8.0, not in earlier versions. You can check the version of your MySQL Server with this query: `SELECT VERSION();`. I have seen that error message and it's certainly the error you would get if your version of MySQL Server were 5.7 or older.

Comment: My Version -  5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. Is my query appropriate for MY SQL 8.0 version?